# Smoothness and composition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, smooth-functions

I have a following problem: 
Suppose f is a k-smooth function ($ \in C^k$) but not $(k+1)$-smooth ($f \notin C^{k+1}$) and $g(x)=ax+b, a\neq 0$). 
Is it true, and if it is than how to prove it, that $f \circ g $ is also a k-smooth function ($ \in C^k$) but is not $k+1$-smooth ($ f \circ g \notin C^{k+1}$)? \

I can't see anywhere such questions. All I see is that the composition doesn't reduce smoothness.

Comment: Hint: you're assuming that $f$ is in $C^k$ but not in $C^{k+1}$, right?  Suppose by way of contradiction that $f \circ g$ is in $C^{k+1}$.  Find a function $h$ such that $g \circ h(x) = x$.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that $f \in C^k$ and $f \notin c^{k+1}$.
Thanks, I'll think about it and see if I'll figure out anything.

Comment: If you're assuming that, please edit your question to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is in $C^k$ but not in $C^{k+1}$.  We want to show that $f \circ g$ is also in $C^k$ but not in $C^{k+1}$.  Since $f \circ g(x) = f(ax+b)$, it is not difficult to see that $f \circ g$ belongs to $C^k$.  The problem is to show that $f \circ g$ does not belong to $C^{k+1}$.

Suppose by way of contradiction it does belong to $C^{k+1}$.  Let $h(x) = \frac{1}{a}x - \frac{b}{a}$.  It is not difficult to see that $g(h(x)) = x$.  Since $f \circ g$ belongs to $C^{k+1}$, so does $(f \circ g) \circ h$.  But

$$ (f \circ g) \circ h(x) = f(g(h(x)) = f(x)$$
In other words, $(f \circ g) \circ h = f$.  This is a contradiction, since we assumed that  $f$ did not belong to $C^{k+1}$.